# Basic Scheme Recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme

I have a file like this:

```
    declare
    a = aexpress 
    b = bexpress 
    begin
```

My scheme program sets the current input port to this file then calls
`(declarations (read))`
What im getting back, is `#f`.
or rather the console says "The object #f is not applicable."

I have been over my parenthesis use and cant find any reason it should be returning a boolean value, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

What I want, is ((a aexpress) (b bexpress))

```
(define declarations
  (lambda (token)
    (cond (((eq? token 'begin) '())
           (else (let* ((name token)
                        (eqsign (read))
                        (value (read)))
                   (cons (list name value) (declarations (read)))))))))
```

Called by:

```
    (define convert
      (lambda (filename)

         (begin
           (set-current-input-port! (open-input-file filename))
           (statement (read))
           )

        )
      )
 (define statement (lambda (token) (

                                   cond (
                                     ( (eq? token 'declare) (declarations (read)) )
                                        ;       ( (eq? token 'declare) (declare_statement)  )
                                        ;       ( (eq? token 'begin) (begin_statement) )
                                        ;       ( (eq? token 'for) (for_statement) )
                                        ;       ( (eq? token 'if) (if_statement)  )
                                        ;       ( (eq? token 'set) (set_statement) )
                                        ;       (else (expression_token))


                                   ))))
```

Comment: Which Scheme implementation are you using?

Comment: MIT scheme release 9.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed the code formatting for you, which reveals what the problem is: you have too many layers of brackets around the `(eq? token 'begin)`. The fixed version would look like this:

```
(define declarations
  (lambda (token)
    (cond ((eq? token 'begin) '())
          (else (let* ((name token)
                       (eqsign (read))
                       (value (read)))
                  (cons (list name value) (declarations (read))))))))
```

Comment: I see, I follow that - the issue I was having was I thought it was all supposed to be one parameter of cond, not many.  But taking that suggestion I appear to be getting the same error except...#t. That is1 ]=> (convert "t")

;The object #t is not applicable.

Comment: @Ben: What's `convert`? I don't believe it's in the code you posted. :-(

Comment: Sorry, it wasnt really relevent because I had tested it without convert, but I added it to the original post. In reality the file starts with "declare" which is eaten by convert

Comment: Ah! Nevermind! I see the same error repeated there. Thank you!